# how to use native wifi direct in native winapi?

Tags: windows, winapi, wifi, wifi-direct

I want to use native WIFI DIRECT API in WINDOWS API.

(NOT USE Proximity in WinRT)

but there is nowhere sample or tutorial.

how to use native wifi direct in native winapi?

or where is sample or tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN, WiFi Direct API is available for Desktop Apps.

So if you enable C++/CX as described [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/pavely/2012/09/29/using-ccx-in-desktop-apps/) you can integrate code from [Microsoft's examples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/WiFiDirect/cpp) into your app.

Comment: Here is link to msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.wifidirect.wifidirectdevice.aspx Marked as DualApiPartition

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.